# Track a satellite using python

Tags: tracking, python, sgp4

I tried tracking a satellite - or rather confirming the data I got from the [AMSAT pass prediction web page](https://www.amsat.org/track/index.php) - using python, more precisly the sgp4 and navpy packages.
Now I don't really now what I'm doing here, but I thought this would work:

```
from sgp4.api import Satrec
from sgp4.api import jday
import navpy
import numpy as np

#ISS

s = '1 25544U 98067A   21336.70775771  .00004247  00000-0  85987-4 0  9994'
t = '2 25544  51.6437 229.4568 0004362 271.6918 182.8759 15.48732282314711'
satellite = Satrec.twoline2rv(s, t)

jd, fr = jday(2021, 12, 8, 9, 4, 0)
e, r, v = satellite.sgp4(jd, fr) # e = error, r = position vector, v = speed vector

lat, lon, alt = 48.1, 16.3, 250 
r0 = navpy.lla2ecef(lat, lon, alt, latlon_unit='deg', alt_unit='m', model='wgs84')

x, y, z = r - r0
az = np.arctan2(x,y)
el = np.arctan2(z,y)
az_deg = 180*az/np.pi
el_deg = 180*el/np.pi
```

What I expected from this code is, that it would give me a simillar output to what the AMSAT page those, i.e., give me elevation and azimuth of the satellite, relative to my position (r0) at a certain time. However, the results don't match at all and I suspect it has something to do with the used coordinate systems, but I can't point my finger at it.
Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

It's the coordinate system.  You need an additional tool to make the conversion.  It's right there on the home page (https://pypi.org/project/sgp4/):

> Note that the SGP4 propagator returns raw x,y,z Cartesian coordinates
> in a “True Equator Mean Equinox” (TEME) reference frame that’s
> centered on the Earth but does not rotate with it — an “Earth centered
> inertial” (ECI) reference frame. The SGP4 propagator itself does not
> implement the math to convert these positions into more official ECI
> frames like J2000 or the ICRF; nor to convert positions into any
> Earth-centered Earth-fixed (ECEF) frames like the ITRS; nor to convert
> them to latitudes and longitudes through an Earth ellipsoid like
> WGS84.
>
> For conversions into other coordinate frames, look for a comprehensive
> astronomy library that is built atop this one, like the Skyfield
> library

Note carefully that TEME is ***an*** ECI frame, ***not*** the ***only*** ECI frame.  There are many different options for ECI, each of which tries to be "inertial" in a slightly different way, though none of them succeed exactly.  Similarly, WGS84 is ***an*** ECEF frame, ***not*** the ***only*** ECEF frame.  In fact, SGP4 is so old, that it actually uses WGS72 internally.

Comment: It is not obvious to me how to use Skyfield to make my code work, can you explain further? (As I commented below, M2FKXY's code works for me, but I'd be interested in wrapping my head around this.

Answer (score 3):

What are the results when using [skyfield](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/)? Here is some sample code to print an azimuth and elevation at a certain time, and avoid any reference frame and coordinates manipulations.

```
from skyfield.api import load, wgs84

ts = load.timescale()

satUrl = 'http://celestrak.com/NORAD/elements/active.txt'
sats = load.tle_file(satUrl)
print('Loaded', len(sats), 'satellites')

>> Loaded 4848 satellites

satNames = {sat.name: sat for sat in sats}
sat = satNames["SENTINEL-1A"]
print(sat)

>> SENTINEL-1A catalog #39634 epoch 2021-12-08 08:16:29 UTC

myPos = wgs84.latlon(+60, +25)

t0 = ts.utc(2021, 12, 10, 0)
t1 = ts.utc(2021, 12, 10, 12)

t, events = sat.find_events(myPos, t0, t1, altitude_degrees = 20)

for ti, event in zip(t, events):
    name = ("rise above 20°", "culminate", "set below 20°")[event]
    print(ti.utc_strftime('%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S'), name)
    
>> 2021 Dec 10 05:11:52 rise above 20°
>> 2021 Dec 10 05:15:11 culminate
>> 2021 Dec 10 05:18:30 set below 20°
>> 2021 Dec 10 06:50:38 rise above 20°
>> 2021 Dec 10 06:52:21 culminate
>> 2021 Dec 10 06:54:05 set below 20°

t = ts.utc(2021, 12, 10, 5, 15, 11)

diff = sat - myPos
topocentric = diff.at(t)
alt, az, dist = topocentric.altaz()

print("Altitude ", alt, "; azimuth ", az, " at ", t.utc_strftime(), )      
        
>> Altitude  85deg 49' 06.4" ; azimuth  105deg 50' 27.2"  at  2021-12-10 05:15:11 UTC
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the same AOS and LOS data as with the mentioned pass prediction tool. Is it correct that I would have to correct for a observer altitude (my altitude) myself? The code does not take this into account, right?

Comment: @RadaD, to account for your altitude construct myPos = wgs84.latlon(lat, lon, alt) where alt (altitude relative to ellipsoid) is an extra parameters (units in meters). It's not obvious at all in the Skyfield documentation that you can do this.